# Pytest assert return 401 instead of 200 when test login in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pytest

I do not know what is wrong with this code when I am trying to test login, first assert passed so user created successfully but failed in second assert.

Hint: I am using simple JWT

Test Code:

```
from user.models import User
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from mixer.backend.django import mixer
from django.urls import reverse
import pytest

client = APIClient()

@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestUser():
   
   @pytest.fixture
   def setup_user(self):
          user = mixer.blend(User, email='a@a.com', password='1')
          return user

   def test_login(self, setup_user):
          assert User.objects.count() == 1 
          data = {'email': 'a@a.com', 'password': '1'}
          response = client.post(reverse('login'), data=data)
          assert response.status_code == 200
```

URL:

```
    path('api/login/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='login'),
```

ERROR:

```
FAILED user/tests/test_user.py::TestUser::test_login - assert 401 == 200
```

Comment: Can you show your login view?

Comment: I am using simple JWT

Comment: Can you try changing `email` to `username` in `data`?

Comment: I set ''' USERNAME_FIELD = 'email ''' in custom user model and It is working fine in postman and return 200 with Bearer Token

Comment: I see. How about the call to `mixer`? Can you confirm if it did create the `User` and also hashed the password correctly?

Comment: Yup, As you see in first assert I check if `mixer` created the `user` or not and it passed

Comment: How about the hash? Not sure if mixer will hash the password for you. You might have to call `set_password` separately and then `save` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record: You need to set the password correctly to be able to hash it, in order for the login to work:

```
   @pytest.fixture
   def setup_user(self):
          user = mixer.blend(User, email='a@a.com')
          user.set_password('1')
          user.save()
          return user
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding `format="json"` to your client post call

Comment: The same problem.

Comment: also data=json.dumps(data)

Comment: I think the problem is not from json format